# Talend Open Studio - Iterate all X rows and not for each row

Tags: loops, iteration, row, talend

I used talend for data extraction and insertion into OTSDB. But I need to cut my file, and a classic iteration take too much time (40 rows/s and I have 90 millions rows).

Do you know how to send for example 50 rows by 50 rows instead of each row individually?

Answer (score 0):

The writing mode can be adjusted for many talend components.
The tMysqlOutput component for example can be configured to do an insert every X rows.

The tFileOutputDelimited (eg. CSV) has a setting for the flush buffer size.

Have a closer look at your component's advanced settings.